# Rails 4 - Nested resource routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a course and syllabus models defined like this

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :enrollments
    has_many :students, through: :enrollments, class_name: "User"
    has_many :syllabuses

end

class Syllabus < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :course
end
```

Routes defined like this

```
resources :courses do
    resource :syllabuses
  end
```

My html has a link to edit syllabus

```
<td><%= link_to "Edit", edit_course_syllabuses_path, class: "btn btn-primary"  %></td>
```

rake routes shows me this

```
edit_course_syllabuses GET    /courses/:course_id/syllabuses/edit(.:format) syllabuses#edit
```

server log  shows the request processing like

```
Started GET "/courses/46/syllabuses/edit" for ::1 at 2015-02-04 20:55:43 +0530
Processing by SyllabusesController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"course_id"=>"46"}
  Syllabus Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "syllabuses".* FROM "syllabuses" WHERE "syllabuses"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", nil]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 2ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find Syllabus with 'id'=:
```

How to pass the syllabus id to the syllabus controller edit action ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a `has_many` association, you also need `resources :syllabuses` (note the **s**).

Change that, restart the server and run the following code to see all routes:

```
bundle exec rake routes
```

Your path would be now `edit_course_syllabuse` and you can just use it like:

```
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_course_syllabuses_path(@syllabuse), class: "btn btn-primary"  %>
```

You can read more about nested resources in [Raild guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)

Comment: @PRN happy that I could help!